# JDBC connection pool occasionally becomes unavailable (not registered) through JNDI

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, eclipselink, payara

I'm seeing some problems with making queries to a database unpredictably.

This is an application hosted on Payara 4, connecting to an Oracle database using EclipseLink. We've seen it occur in our production environment, on two instances. It appears that it occurs at higher times of usage, though I'm not sure if that's because it's the cause or because there's more requests so it's more likely to happen.

Below is a graph that shows the number of failed requests (in red) and successful requests (in grey):
[image: graph of failed requests and successful requests]

I've confirmed that there are no issues on the database side, e.g. dropped connections.

The following is the error that occurs on the failure (although it happens on many queries):

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: This pool is not registered with the runtime environment : <redacted>
Error Code: 0
Call: <redacted>
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: DoesExistQuery(<redacted>)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.performPreQueryFlush(QueryImpl.java:967)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
    at <redacted>
    at <redacted>
    at <redacted>
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6005.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4836)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3907.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3908.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4808)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4796)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy132454.<redacted>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6004.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:239)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at <redacted>
    at <redacted>
    at <redacted>
    at <redacted>
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1692)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at <redacted>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:483)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: This pool is not registered with the runtime environment : <redacted>
Error Code: 0
Call: <redacted>
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: DoesExistQuery(<redacted>)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.reconnect(DatasourceAccessor.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.reconnect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.incrementCallCount(DatasourceAccessor.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2056)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectRowForDoesExist(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DoesExistQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DoesExistQuery.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1790)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.checkForUnregisteredExistingObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4192)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:951)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:929)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:2515)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(CollectionMapping.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:2515)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(CollectionMapping.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:2515)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(CollectionMapping.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:2515)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:951)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:929)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:2515)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.discoverUnregisteredNewObjects(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:723)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:874)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: This pool is not registered with the runtime environment : <redacted>
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:1558)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.getConnection(ConnectorRuntime.java:639)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
    ... 136 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: This pool is not registered with the runtime environment : <redacted>
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getUnpooledConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:583)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:1550)
    ... 139 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: This pool is not bound in JNDI : <redacted>
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.obtainManagedConnectionFactory(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:1022)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.obtainManagedConnectionFactory(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:911)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getUnpooledConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:576)
    ... 140 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/<redacted>' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: <redacted> not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.naming.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getConnectorConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:799)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.obtainManagedConnectionFactory(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:938)
    ... 142 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: <redacted> not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:70)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:483)
    ... 148 more
```

Additionally, in the `server.log`, I've there's the following [RAR messages](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1755/gjkmf/index.html). These only seem to occur when the usage exceeds a certain amount:

- `RAR6021: Failed to remove the MCF : <connection_pool>`
- `RAR5114: Error allocating connection : [Task already scheduled or cancelled]`
- `RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [null]`
- `RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [This pool is not registered with the runtime environment : <connection_pool>]`
- `RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [This pool is not bound in JNDI : <connection_pool><connection_pool>]`
- `RAR7010: Pool not reachable.`

There is also one instance of `RAR6021 :Failed to create MCF : <connection_pool>` in a single day; however, I'm unsure whether this is related.

What could be causing this? Are there any techniques that could be use to diagnose the issue?

Comment: It's an old problem: Google finds links from back in 2011 for your error.  Intermittent errors are impossible.  Ask Oracle.  I'd wonder why you persist wth opaque, complex technologies like Oracle, EJB, EclipseLink, etc.  There are lighter, simpler alternatives.

Comment: A huge backlog of legacy web applications is the main reason here, most more than 15 years old! And this is definitely some of the best of the legacy systems that we have. Definitely looking at lighter and simpler alternatives when it comes to re-implementation.

Comment: I've looked using Google but I've struggled to find solution to intermittent problems. Most of the discussion is around where it is a permanent issue.

Comment: 15 years with no upgrades?  That's what you ought to be reconsidering.

Comment: I don't think that sort of comment is helpful at all. This problem that I'm having exists and is **valid** whether or not the technology I'm asking the question about is the best practice. To give some context, the backlog of legacy (and business critical) software has been inherited and I have not made the business decisions that lead us here. We are upgrading and re-implementing software; however, it takes time and resources, both of which are limited.

Comment: No chat for me.

Comment: I increased the JDBC connection pool minimum and maximum sizes and this **hasn't** occurred during high usage. Previously, it was min 2 and max 16, now it's min 4 and max 32. I don't understand why this has fixed (or just pushed it back until higher usage) the issue enough for this to be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in our server Payara 4.1.2.173 build 24 the solution was remove the JDBC Connection Pool and recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in my case I use Glassfish 4 and after making many changes in the settings, increasing memory, cores, etc. I read the Ignaco Novello's comment advising to remove and recreate the jdbc connection pool and to my surprise it worked perfectly. (y)